# Write to a file in C

Tags: c

In **C** programming I have learned about `file io` and I have run the sample code which is:

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()

{

 FILE *fp;

 fp = fopen("E:\\tmp\bae.txt", "w+");
 fprintf(fp, "This is testing for fprintf...\n");
 fputs("This is testing for fputs...\n", fp);
 fclose(fp);

 return 0;
}
```

Here the code works fine and `fputs()` returns -1 which means the code works fine. I have created a directory `tmp` on the E: drive, but this code doesn't create the file `bae.txt`..'

Can anyone tell me why this is happening?

Comment: You've got the control sequence `\b` in your filename, which is a backspace. Use the sequence `\\` to get a single backslash, just as you did with the first backslash.

Comment: You should also check whether the file could be opened and act accordingly if not. And an `fputs` return value of -1 does not mean that "the code works fine"; on the contrary, it indicates an error.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of

```
 fp = fopen("E:\\tmp\bae.txt", "w+");
```

use

```
 fp = fopen("E:\\tmp\\bae.txt", "w+");
```

as `\` has specific meaning in a string.

Comment: That's got **absolutely nothing** to do with `printf` (or with any other function for that matter). The preprocessor simply replaces the `\b` with whatever control character it represnts (backspace, I believe).

Comment: yeah sorry .I did not mean to associate it with printf though I ended up writing it.

Comment: The problem would persist even if `\b` did not have "specific meaning in a string" (i.e., the problem is due to the missing backslash, regardless of what character comes after it).